# How can I export a bunch of Nagios services from Groundwork?

Tags: export, nagios

I want to move a bunch of services from one instance of Groundwork to another. Is there any way to export all my services from Groundwork?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Configuration/Tools/Export to files

Monarch will export all of the config files individually. You can download and transfer at will.